# Spring Boot - Validation of Repository Queries

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have updated my application to Spring Boot 3. I'm not 100% sure, but if I can remember correct, befoere Spring checks on application startup whether the parameter of the Object fit together:

```
@Query("SELECT new test.UserView(u.userName, u.firstName, u.secondName) FROM User u WHERE u.userName = :userName") 
UserView getUserLoginView(@Param("userName") String userName;
```

In this example the field secondName is missing, but I do not receive an error on startup:

```
public class UserView {
    private String userName;
    private String firstName;
    
    public UserView(String userName, String firstName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

Is there a property which needs to be activated?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that when we use constructor expressions in jpql select method, spring cannot able to validate if your constructor has been well define on startup.

Spring certainly validates all the queries at startup but it only checks the SQL syntax, the correct names of the entities and their attributes. therefore does not check [constructor expressions](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select). What is reassuring is that during runtime if the right constructor is not found for the `UserView` class on `getUserLoginView()` call an exception will be thrown for missing constructor (`IllegalStateException`)

I think no need to activate something for that. Unit tests will be able to check if your method has been well defined at this level.